# Three.js: for loop for every mesh in scene?

Tags: javascript, three.js

So what I want is to do something like

```
scene.forEachMeshInScene(function(mesh){
      //And here I can do stuff
});
```

But sadly, that doesn't exist. How can I do something like this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the following pattern to iterate over the `Mesh` objects in the `scene` graph:

```
scene.traverse( function( node ) {

    if ( node instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {

        // insert your code here, for example:
        node.material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial()

    }

} );
```

three.js r.69